# AdonisJs - How to equal my date field with my date from database

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, adonis.js

I created a view with just a date input to query a register by created_at field.
My date input search for  ?date=2020-07-10, while my database saves like Data: Fri Jul 10 2020 08:41:12 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00). This way my search always fails and find nothing

How to equal my date field with my date from database?

My View

```
<form action="/buscarpordata" method="GET">
    <h1 class="title is-4 column is-4 is-offset-4">Buscar Nota por Data</h1>
  <div class="field is-grouped column is-4 is-offset-4">
    
<input type="date" name="data" required>
  
    <br><div  style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <p class="control">
        <input type="submit" class="button is-primary is-medium is-6" value="Buscar">
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

My migration

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class NotaSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('notas', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.string('numero')
      //FORNECEDOR FK
      table.integer('id_fornecedor_fk')
      .unsigned()
      .references('id')
      .inTable('fornecedors')
      .onUpdate('CASCADE')
      .onDelete('CASCADE')
      //USUARIO FK
      table.integer('id_usuario_fk')
            .unsigned()
            .references('id')
            .inTable('users')
            .onUpdate('CASCADE')
            .onDelete('CASCADE')
   
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('notas')
  }
}

module.exports = NotaSchema
```

My Model

```
class Nota extends Model {

    usuario () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
    }

    fornecedor () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Fornecedor')
    }
}
```

My Controller (to add register)

```
const nota = new Nota();

nota.numero = request.input('numero')
nota.id_fornecedor_fk= request.input('fornecedor')
nota.id_usuario_fk = auth.user.id

try {

await nota.save()
return response.redirect('/notas')
}

catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

My SearchController to make the Query

```
async searchpordata({request, response, session, view}) {
let query2 = request.input('data')
const notas = await Database
.select('notas.id', 'numero', 'notas.created_at', 'fornecedors.nome', 'fornecedors.cnpj', 'username')
.from('notas')
.where('notas.created_at', query2)
.join('fornecedors', 'fornecedors.id', 'id_fornecedor_fk')
.join('users', 'users.id', 'id_usuario_fk').first()

if(notas)
{
  console.log(notas)
return view.render('resultado_notapordata',{
  notas: notas,
  
  })     
}

else {
return view.render('resultado_buscanota_erro')
}  
   
}
```

MY route when i try to request

```
http://127.0.0.1:3333/buscarpordata?data=2020-07-11
```

So o cant find any register

Answer (score 0):

First what is the definition for the `created_at` column? In other words what type is being stored as?

Second your issue is probably more a case of comparing a date to to timestamp then one of format:

```
select '2020-07-10'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 07/10/2020 00:00:00

 select '2020-07-10'::date = 'Fri Jul 10 2020 08:41:12-0300'::timestamp;
 ?column? 
----------
 f

--When you do the above the date gets changed to timestamp form to compare 
--against the timestamp value.

select 'Fri Jul 10 2020 08:41:12-0300'::date;
 date    
------------
 07/10/2020

select '2020-07-10'::date = 'Fri Jul 10 2020 08:41:12-0300'::date;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

--Now they are both being compared as dates.
```

Comment: Hi Adrian. Thanks for the help. I updated my post writing my migration created_at is the timestamps in my migration. Its a field that saves the creation date of my register. it returns: 2020-07-10 08:41:12-03

Comment: I would make that clear at the top of the question. Honestly most folks will not go through every line of code to find that.  Anyway the problem is as I outlined above and also indicated by your question 'How to equal my date field with my date from database?' The data in your database is a timestamp not a date and you are comparing it to date and it fails for the reason above.

Comment: Just to be clear you don't need to change the timestamp field to a date field, just cast ```created_at``` to ```DATE``` when doing the comparison.